# Ionic 7 modal not working on second click

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am opening a modal from a tab button.  It works fine the first time i click the button but after that it wont work anymore.   after i click it the first time i get the following warning in the console.

> A trigger element with the ID "open-modal" was not found in the DOM.
> The trigger element must be in the DOM when the "trigger" property is
> set on an overlay component.

html:

```
<ion-modal trigger="open-modal" > 
        <ng-template>
        <ion-header>
          <ion-toolbar>
            <ion-buttons slot="start">
              <ion-button (click)="closeModal()">Close</ion-button>
            </ion-buttons>
            <ion-title>Privacy Policy</ion-title> 
          </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-header>
        <ion-content class="ion-padding">
          <ion-item> 
          </ion-item>
        </ion-content> 
    </ng-template>
    </ion-modal>



 <ion-tabs>
        <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
          <ion-tab-button  >
            <ion-icon name="chatbubbles"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>Contact Us</ion-label>
          </ion-tab-button>
          <ion-tab-button  >
            <ion-icon name="trash-bin"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>Delete Your Account</ion-label>
          </ion-tab-button>

          <ion-tab-button id="open-modal">
            <ion-icon name="shield-half-outline"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>Privacy Policy</ion-label>
          </ion-tab-button> 
        </ion-tab-bar>
      </ion-tabs>
```

ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AlertController, IonModal, LoadingController, MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'; 
import { AuthenticationService } from 'src/app/system/services/authentication-service/authentication.service';
 

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss']
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild(IonModal) privacyPolicyModal: IonModal;

    credentials: FormGroup;
    constructor(
        public menu: MenuController,
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private authService: AuthenticationService,
        private alertController: AlertController,
        private router: Router,
        private loadingController: LoadingController
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.credentials = this.fb.group({
            username: ['', [Validators.required]],
            password: ['', [Validators.required]]
        });
    }

 
  ionViewWillEnter() { 
    this.menu.enable(false);
  }

  
  closeModal(): void{
    this.privacyPolicyModal.dismiss(null, 'cancel');        
  }

    async login() {
        const loading = await this.loadingController.create();
        await loading.present();

        this.authService.login(this.credentials.value).subscribe(
            async (res) => {
                await loading.dismiss();
                this.router.navigateByUrl('/tabs', { replaceUrl: true });
            },
            async (res) => {
                await loading.dismiss(); 
                const alert = await this.alertController.create({
                    header: 'Login failed',
                    message: res.error.error,
                    buttons: ['OK']
                });

                await alert.present();
            }
        );
    }
 
    get username() {
        return this.credentials.get('username');
    }

    get password() {
        return this.credentials.get('password');
    }

  ionViewDidLeave() { 
    this.menu.enable(true);
  }
}
```

i have tried placing the modal html in different spots (before the tabs, after the tabs etc..) but same result each time.

Comment: How you are opening the modal, on any button click? can you provide complete ts code related to modal!

Comment: i am opening with  trigger="open-modal"  on the modal with a tab button having that id.  its in the code above.    sorry there is no other relevant code for this problem

Comment: update: if i  remove id="open-modal from the tab button and create and ion-button and put the button inside <ion-content> everything works fine.  so its definitely only a problem when the being triggered by an element in the tabs

Answer (score 4):

`ion-tabs` are usually for active states, not one time actions. I'm not sure about the exact reason, but this might be why the modal couldn't find the trigger in the DOM (hence the warning).

In this case, I suggest using `isOpen` attribute instead of `trigger` and make sure you manage your states correctly. something like that:

```
<ion-modal [isOpen]="openModal" (didDismiss)="closeModal()"> 
        <ng-template>
        <ion-header>
          <ion-toolbar>
            <ion-buttons slot="start">
              <ion-button (click)="closeModal()">Close</ion-button>
            </ion-buttons>
            <ion-title>Privacy Policy</ion-title> 
          </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-header>
        <ion-content class="ion-padding">
          <ion-item> 
          </ion-item>
        </ion-content> 
    </ng-template>
    </ion-modal>

 <ion-tabs>
        <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
          <ion-tab-button >
            <ion-icon name="chatbubbles"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>Contact Us</ion-label>
          </ion-tab-button>
          <ion-tab-button >
            <ion-icon name="trash-bin"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>Delete Your Account</ion-label>
          </ion-tab-button>

          <ion-tab-button (click)="openModal = true">
            <ion-icon name="shield-half-outline"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>Privacy Policy</ion-label>
          </ion-tab-button> 
        </ion-tab-bar>
      </ion-tabs>
```

```
closeModal(){
    this.openModal = false;
}
```

also make sure to handle css properties as well. like the class `selected`, which would be appended to every active tab button, thus make them look like an active button.

Comment: thank you very much for the response.  i just ended up navigating to a new page instead of a modal.  seemed like the best solution.  thank you again!

Comment: @JoeJohnson great. that is a better thing to do, UX-wise.